# change images before save in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm creating photo app in my free time but I am wondring how can I set width and hight for image before saving  it in photo folder

```
@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePiker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePiker.delegate = self;
        imagePiker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePiker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePiker.allowsEditing =NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePiker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender {
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        imagePicker.delegate =  self ;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        i
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = YES;
    }

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,
                                           self,
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                           nil);
    }
    else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
    {
        // Code here to support video if enabled
    }
}

-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



@end
```

Comment: do you want to resize the image before saving image ?

Answer (score -1):

Resize the `UIImage` object retrieved from the picker before calling `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`. [Here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) is some good code for easily resizing an image.